# Using Middle Join Tables in a Complicated SQL Query

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2019

I've inherited a project from a business partner and am trying to add to it, but am running against the wind here.
It's a cocktail database consisting of 7 tables.

```
drinks (ID, drinkName, lu_category, lu_glassware, lu_IBA)
category (categoryID, category)
glassware (glasswareID, glassware)
ingredients (ingredientID, ingredient, notes)
measure (measureID, measure)
IBA (IBAID, IBA)
ingredient_drinks_measure (idmID, drinkID, ingredientID, measureID)
```

This query works as expected and pulls back everything in a single row per drink.

```
SELECT        dbo.drinks.id AS [drinkID], 
              dbo.drinks.drinkName, 
              dbo.category.category, 
              dbo.glassware.glassware, 
              dbo.IBA.IBA, 
              string_agg(measure.measure + ' ' + ingredients.ingredient, ', ') as [Ingredients]
FROM          dbo.glassware 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.measure 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure ON dbo.measure.measureID = dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.measureID 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ingredients ON dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.ingredientID = dbo.ingredients.ingredientID 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.drinks ON dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.drinkID = dbo.drinks.id 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IBA ON dbo.drinks.lu_IBA = dbo.IBA.IBAID ON dbo.glassware.glasswareID = dbo.drinks.lu_glassware 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.category ON dbo.drinks.lu_category = dbo.category.categoryID
GROUP BY      dbo.drinks.id, 
              dbo.drinks.drinkName, 
              dbo.drinks.imagePath, 
              dbo.drinks.dateModified, 
              dbo.category.category, 
              dbo.glassware.glassware, 
              dbo.IBA.IBA
```

returns

```
drinkID | drinkName | category  | glassware         | IBA                   | ingredients
11000   | Mojito    | Cocktail  | Highball glass    | Contemporary Classics | 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar
```

I now need to add TAGS to each drink
There are only 22 tags (at the moment) and each drink can have 1 to 22 tags associated with it (the tags are like 'Halloween', 'Christmas', 'Punch Bowl', 'Breakfast', 'Dinner Party', 'Fruity', 'Boozy', etc.).

I have a `tags table (id, tag)` and I have a `drinkTags table (drinkID, tagID)` sitting in the middle to combine drinks and the tags together (the CREATE scripts for both are down below).

However, no matter how I try, when I add in the joins to the query and an attendant string_agg column for the TAGS (comma separated aggregate column), at least one of the string_agg columns gets duplicated and/or I get multiple rows per drink.
such as this:

```
drinkID | drinkName | category  | glassware         | IBA                   | ingredients
11000   | Mojito    | Cocktail  | Highball glass    | Contemporary Classics | 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar, 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar, 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar
```

or this:

```
drinkID | drinkName | category  | glassware         | IBA                   | tags      | ingredients
11000   | Mojito    | Cocktail  | Highball glass    | Contemporary Classics | Alcoholic | 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar
11000   | Mojito    | Cocktail  | Highball glass    | Contemporary Classics | IBA       | 2 tsp Superfine Sugar, Juice of 1 Lime, 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum
11000   | Mojito    | Cocktail  | Highball glass    | Contemporary Classics | USA       | 2-3 oz Jamaican Rum, Juice of 1 Lime, 2 tsp Superfine Sugar
```

Any thoughts? I'd appreciate any assistance even if it's just pointing me to something I've overlooked in all of my research.

Here are the CREATE scripts if you want them.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[drinks]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:25:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[drinks](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [drinkName] [varchar](37) NOT NULL,
    [lu_category] [int] NULL,
    [lu_IBA] [int] NULL,
    [lu_glassware] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK__drinks_c__2B658F5CD9E4315A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[category]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:27:18 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[category](
    [categoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [category] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__category__23CAF1F80317C8FA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [categoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[drinkTags]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:27:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[drinkTags](
    [drinkID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tagID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_drinkTags_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [drinkID] ASC,
    [tagID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO




/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[glassware]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:28:08 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[glassware](
    [glasswareID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [glassware] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [glasswareID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IBA]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:28:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IBA](
    [IBAID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IBA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IBAID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ingredient_drinks_measure]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:28:32 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ingredient_drinks_measure](
    [idmID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [drinkID] [int] NULL,
    [ingredientID] [int] NULL,
    [measureID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idmID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ingredients]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:28:44 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ingredients](
    [ingredientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ingredient] [nvarchar](150) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ingredientID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[measure]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:29:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[measure](
    [measureID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [measure] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [measureID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tags]    Script Date: 9/15/2020 1:29:25 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tags](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tag] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_drinkTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:

Does a drink have one-to-one relationship with a tag? If that is true then all you need to do is to add a tag column to the drink table. This will a de-normalized way of solving the problem.

## Solution 2:

If the drink do not have one-to-one relationship with the tag entity.
Which table stores the relationship between drinks and tags? If you do not have this table then you need to create one and populate with data. If you need help in creating the drinks to tag relationship then I can help you with that. Then you will need to update the SQL to use the tag to drink relationship to get single record and also add the tag field in the SQL.

Comment: Each drink can have many tags so it's definitely not a 1-to-1 relationship. There is a tags table which stores the tagID and the tag name, there is also a table I named drinkTags that stores the drinkID and the tagID. So, as a continuation of the examples I gave in my post, the drinkTags table would have 3 entries for drinkID #11000. It's joining those two tables and adding the string_agg column that seems to be giving me fits.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the query below will solve your problem. I have added one string_agg field to return all the tags associated with a drink and two INNER JOINS.

```
SELECT        dbo.drinks.id AS [drinkID], 
              dbo.drinks.drinkName, 
              dbo.category.category, 
              dbo.glassware.glassware, 
              dbo.IBA.IBA, 
              string_agg(measure.measure + ' ' + ingredients.ingredient, ', ') as [Ingredients],
          string_agg(dbo.tags.tag, ', ‘) as [Tags]
FROM          dbo.glassware 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.measure 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure ON dbo.measure.measureID = dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.measureID 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ingredients ON dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.ingredientID = dbo.ingredients.ingredientID 
              RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.drinks ON dbo.ingredient_drinks_measure.drinkID = dbo.drinks.id 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IBA ON dbo.drinks.lu_IBA = dbo.IBA.IBAID ON dbo.glassware.glasswareID = dbo.drinks.lu_glassware 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.category ON dbo.drinks.lu_category = dbo.category.categoryID
          INNER JOIN  dbo.drinkTags.drinkID =  dbo.drinks.id    
          INNER JOIN  dbo.tags.id = dbo.drinkTags.tagID
GROUP BY      dbo.drinks.id, 
              dbo.drinks.drinkName, 
              dbo.drinks.imagePath, 
              dbo.drinks.dateModified, 
              dbo.category.category, 
              dbo.glassware.glassware, 
              dbo.IBA.IBA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm afraid that's quite similar to the results I have been getting.
In this instance both the Ingredients column and the Tags column were getting duplicated inside the string_agg equal to the number of items needing to be aggregated: 
e.g. there are three tags (Alcoholic, IBA, USA) repeated three times in a comma-separated column. The same is true of the 3 ingredients (Rum, Lime, Sugar) being repeated 3 times in a comma-separated column.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research, I have found a solution that will work for me. This does make a presumption that there is at least one tag per drinkID, but I can deal with that for the moment.

```
;WITH a AS
(
SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.drinkName as [Name] ,
    c.category as [Category],
    g.glassware as [Glass],
    b.IBA as [IBA],
    string_agg(m.measure + ' ' + i.ingredient, ', ') as [Ingredients],
    d.instructions as [Instructions],
    string_agg(i.notes, ', ') as [IngredientNotes],
    d.addedInfo as [Additional Information],
    d.imagePath as [Image]
FROM drinks d
    JOIN category c on c.categoryID = d.lu_category
    JOIN glassware g on g.glasswareID = d.lu_glassware
    LEFT JOIN IBA b on b.IBAID = d.lu_IBA
    JOIN ingredient_drinks_measure idm on idm.drinkID = d.id
    JOIN ingredients i on i.ingredientID = idm.ingredientID
    JOIN measure m on m.measureID = idm.measureID
group by d.id, d.drinkName, c.category, g.glassware, b.IBA, d.addedInfo, d.imagePath, d.instructions
)
SELECT a.*, dtm.tags
FROM a
JOIN (select 
        drinkID, string_agg(t.tag, ', ') as tags
        from tags t
        join tagmap tm on tm.tagID = t.id
        group by drinkID) as dtm
ON a.ID = dtm.drinkID
```